# How can I legally avoid recruiting a specific nationality/ethnicity?

Tags: united-states, employment, discrimination

Suppose I have a tech company and I don't want to recruit people of a specific nationality (say, Hungarian) or ethnicity (say, East Indian).

Is there any legal way to do that?

Comment: Move to a country with no anti-discrimination legislation?

Comment: Would really be good if the downvoters gave any reason for that. "This in ethically questionable and should not be done" is not a reason to downvote.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You would need to argue that you picked that *other* guy because he had better qualifications. Or that you couldn't hire an Indian because it was unlikely he would get a work permit.

If it really comes to a court case, the jury would have to decide whether they believe you or whether they think you're making up a flimsy excuse.

Answer (score 3):

### No

This is a clear violation of anti-discrimination law in employment which prohibits discrimination on the basis of race, ethnicity or nationality.

Comment: Obviously. But as I wrote in my answer, this just needs to be concealed with some other argument. It will be very hard to prove (as the applicant who did not get the job) that the actual reason was because the employer is a racist.

Comment: @PMF so, robbing banks and murder are legal if you have an alibi?

Comment: Well, good point. It's all about not getting caught ;-)

Comment: @PMF no it isn’t. Illegal is illegal even if nobody knows.

Comment: That was sarcastic.